# mod_proxy_html garbles non-ASCII characters

Tags: apache-2.2, reverse-proxy, centos6

I've set up a reverse proxy with mod_proxy, mod_proxy_html (3.1.3) and mod_xml2enc on a CentOS 6.4 box.

The proxy serves up the target server just fine, but it garbles non-ASCII characters (in my case 'äöüéàè').

I've googled all over the map trying to find a solution to this but to no avail.

The encoding is correctly specified in the response header and identical to the one of the target server (utf-8). I've also tried explicity setting the encoding used by xml2enc via:

```
xml2EncDefault utf-8
```

but to no effect.

I'm running the proxy off a vhost with the proxy configuration set as follows:

```
ProxyRequests off

ProxyHTMLLinks  a               href
ProxyHTMLLinks  area            href
ProxyHTMLLinks  link            href
ProxyHTMLLinks  img             src longdesc usemap
ProxyHTMLLinks  object          classid codebase data usemap
ProxyHTMLLinks  q               cite
ProxyHTMLLinks  blockquote  cite
ProxyHTMLLinks  ins             cite
ProxyHTMLLinks  del             cite
ProxyHTMLLinks  form            action
ProxyHTMLLinks  input           src usemap
ProxyHTMLLinks  head            profile
ProxyHTMLLinks  base            href
ProxyHTMLLinks  script          src for
ProxyHTMLLinks  iframe          src

ProxyPass /foo/ http://someserver.com/
ProxyPassReverse /foo/ http://www.someserver.com/

<Location /foo/>
   SetOutputFilter INFLATE;proxy-html;DEFLATE
   ProxyPassReverse /
   ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /foo
   ProxyHTMLURLMap http://www.someserver.com /foo
   ProxyHTMLURLMap http://someserver.com /foo
   RequestHeader    unset  Accept-Encoding
</Location>
```

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that 'mod_proxy_html' was innocent in all this.

Declaring the encoding via:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

made the issue go away.

This is a bit odd, as the 'Content-Type' was properly set in the response header.

Comment: This solution has worked for me. In my case, it is strange that the `<meta charset="UTF-8" />` element was not enough (was not taken into account) for the Apache HTTP server to detect the encoding. Reference: The «ProxyHTMLMeta Directive» section of the [mod_proxy_html - Apache HTTP Server Version 2.4](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_html.html) page.